# opening a section of another page in a foundation reveal modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

So I'm trying to have a modal appear  with the content of a section from another page when you click a link. For exmaple.

```
<a href="/otherpage" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
```

Click Me For A Modal

the problem is, I don't want the whole page contents just a section from an accordion drop down which I would like to be expanded in the modal eg. ect..:

```
 <dl class="accordion accorborder" data-accordion="">
        <dd class="accordion-navigation">
            <a href="#p1">Math Foundations I Sem 1</a>
            <div id="p1" class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-6 columns">
                        <h6>code:</h6>HS-ES-38
                        <h6>Offerings:</h6> xxx
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-6 columns">
                        <h6>Course Materials:</h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="xxx">Syllabus</a></li>
                            <li><a href="xxx">Course Contract</a></li>
                            <li><a href="xxx">White Board</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>blah</p>
                <dl class="tabs" data-tab="">
                    <dd class="active"><a href="#p1a">Study Sheets</a></dd>
                    <dd><a href="#p1b">Study Sheets Answer Keys</a></dd>
                    <dd><a href="#p1c">Graded Assignments</a></dd>
                    <dd><a href="#p1d">Graded Assignment Answer Keys</a></dd>
                </dl>
                <div class="tabs-content">
                    <div class="content active" id="p1a">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="x"> example </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

So how would I be able to specify the specific sections of the page, would doing it by ID work? eg

```
<a href="/otherpage#XID" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
```

is there any way to do this in this fashion? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got working using angular foundation over at http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/